# Transitive action on non-orientable $ M $ lifts to orientable double cover

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, lie-groups, differential-topology

Suppose that $ M $ is non-orientable with transitive action by a Lie group $ G $. **Does that imply that some Lie group $ G' $ acts transitively on the orientable double cover $M'$?**

This is true for compact dimension 2: the Klein bottle is an $ \operatorname{SE}_2 $ manifold and so is the torus. The projective plane is an $ \operatorname{SO}_3 $ manifold and so is the sphere.

Morally I think the answer should be yes in general since an orientable double cover should be better behaved than/at least as well behaved as the original non orientable manifold.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a general theory for lifting Lie group actions to covering spaces, see Bredon's monograph "Introduction to compact transformation groups", chapter 1, section 9. In the case of orientation covers one gets that any (effective, continuous) action of a Lie group $G$ on a non-orientable manifold lifts to a $G^\prime$ action on the orientation cover, where $G^\prime$ consists of all lifts of elements of $G$. Thus $G^\prime$ surjects onto $G$ with kernel of order two, and in particular, $G^\prime$ is a Lie group.

If the $G$-action is transitive, then so is the $G^\prime$-action. (Indeed, if $\tilde x, \tilde y$ are points in the covering space, which project to $x, y$, respectively, and $g\in G$ with $g(x)=y$, then one of the two lifts of $g$ takes $\tilde x$ to $\tilde y$).

Comment: Despite the title of the monograph, this applies to arbitrary Lie groups, not just compact?  Also, what is a lift of an element of $G$ (i.e., lift to where)?  Does this mean the pre-image in $\operatorname{Diff}(M')$ of the image of $G$ in $\operatorname{Diff}(M)$?

Comment: @LSpice: Yes, this result is so basic that it does not need compactness. Incidentally, Bredon's book is at https://jfdmath.sitehost.iu.edu/seminar/Bredon,Introduction_to_Compact_Transformation_Groups.pdf. Also everything works in the standard setting of the covering space theory, i.e. the $G$-space need not be a manifold. For you other question: The lift of an element of $G$ to the orientation cover (which is defined functorially).

Comment: Thanks so much for linking to the book! And ya I figured it was basic the only reason I posted to MO is that it was unanswered on MSE for a week.

Answer (score 5):

A theorem of Dick Palais tells us that every Lie algebra action generated by complete vector fields arises from a connected Lie group action. So take any Lie algebra of vector fields arising from a Lie group action (so complete), and pull back by any covering map (so still complete), and there is a Lie group giving that Lie algebra action.

Comment: As Igor points out, for a nonorientable manifold $M$, the set $M'$ of all orientations of its tangent spaces is a 2-1 oriented cover, clearly acted on by all of the diffeomorphisms of $M$, or local diffeomorphisms of $M$, so there is an obvious lift of any Lie group or Lie algebra action.